# Where can i learn all the bytecodes generated by the V8 engine?

Tags: javascript, v8, bytecode

Hello guys i've been looking up on some websites with hope to find out what's the meaning of some bytecode instructions generated by the V8.

but it looks like there isn't much talk about that subject.

fortunately i've found several instructions which has been explained on some websites.
but still there are many more that i haven't found documentation or anything
like `CreateClosure` `SuspendGenerator` `ReThrow` etc...

so i ask the kind people of StackOverflow if one of you have a way to learn those bytecodes in depth i would really appreciate it if you share it.

Comment: They have pretty descriptive names already. What further "meaning" do you need to find?

Comment: they do have descriptive names although you can't know what the instruction CreateClosure actually do without digging a little bit deeper. of course it has something to do with creating "closure" but how does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

(V8 developer here.)

V8's bytecode is an internal implementation detail that may or may not change any day, that's why there's no documentation on each individual code. The only way to learn about the details is to read the [source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/interpreter).

As a JavaScript developer, or even as an embedder of V8 into your own C++ program, there's no reason why you should (need to) care that there even is a bytecode, much less the specific details of it. And if you're simply curious about how V8 is implemented -- well, then the source code is your friend :-)